# Can you fight The Eye of Cthulhu again on Terraria Mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was wanting to get extra Crimstone ore, and mining for it is too complicated. Is there a way I can fight the Eye of Cthulhu again? I am playing on tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you get several lenses (6 on pc, might be different on mobile) from killing the small eyes at night, then take them to a demon altar, you can craft a suspicious looking eye which you can use to summon him again.